# How to pull out entries related to multiple nested categories?

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I have a category set up with nested categories so:

Level1
   -level2
       -level3

In my entries channel each entry can have multiple nested categories so we may have an entry with:

cat1
  -subcat1
      -level3

cat2
  -subcat1
      -level3

The second and third levels will have some categories with the same slug names. So how can I pull out entries with `relatedTo` that will look at the parents of each level and only pull out categories from the correct nest?

------ UPDATE -----

Ok I have come up with a solution that works but if anyone can suggest something better please feel free.

```
{% set sector = 'cat1' %}
{% set topic = 'subcat1' %} 
{# set entries variable outside of for loop #}
{% set entries = '' %}
{% if topic is defined %}
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('theCategoryHandle').slug(sector).level(1).first() %}
{% set catChildren = categories.level(3).children %}
{% for childCat in catChildren %}
    {% if childCat.slug == topic %}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(childCat).find() %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```